# Can I bounce the creatures I've chosen for sacrificing to Annihilator?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Hibernation Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHibernation%20Sliver%5d) in play, which allows me to pay 2 life to return a Sliver to my hand.  My opponent controls an Eldrazi with annihilator 2 and attacks, making me sacrifice 2 permanents.

Can I sacrifice 2 Slivers and then, before the sacrifice resolves, return them to my hand with [Hibernation Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHibernation%20Sliver%5d), so I don't have to sacrifice anything and only have to pay 4 life?

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: The permanents you sacrifice to the annihilator ability are only chosen upon the ability's resolution. Since no player gets priority during its resolution, you can't do anything before the permanents are sacrificed.

Comment: Sounds similar to paying a cost of an activated ability by sacrificing a creature.  You don't get to respond to the casting cost being chosen and bounce the sac'd creature.